# play store set apilevel 14-19 automatically

Tags: android

I uploaded an APK to the app store, it's targeting lollipop, but on Google Play Store it says "API levels 14-19". I can't seem to figure out why the max sdk level is stuck at 19.

compileSdkVersion 22 buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

```
defaultConfig {

    applicationId "be.appwise.test"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 15
    versionName "1.0"
```

Comment: Check your `AndroidManifest.xml` for `<uses-sdk android:maxSdkVersion="19"/>` Maybe you're using a library which specified this.

Comment: thanx @Eugen,you r right i use a library with maxSdkVersion="19"

Answer (score 0):

Check your `AndroidManifest.xml` for `<uses-sdk android:maxSdkVersion="19"/>` Maybe you're using a library which specified this.

Google Play store will use this attribute for filtering however the attribute is generally not needed. From the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html):

> By design, new versions of the platform are fully backward-compatible. Your application should work properly on new versions, provided it uses only standard APIs and follows development best practices.

If you want to remove the attribute try one of these inside the `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="the library package name" />

<uses-sdk tools:node="replace" />
```

Disclaimer: I haven't tested these so I don't know if they work or have any side effects. Please report any results.